# RSS Reader in popup

Tags: javascript, html

So I just tested this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fCt4D/) but i don't have my RSS Reader in the popup instead it is empty now.
How to display this in my popup?

This is my RSS Reader Script what i want put in my popup :

```
<html><head>
<title>New own RSS reader demonstration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<!-- FEED READER START HERE -->
 <div id="feed"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
  /*  O P T I O N S */
   feedURL = 'https://news.google.com/news/feeds?cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=h&ncl=dvaadJqUY6PZt7MP7WyQ1UWmilCSM&output=rss';
  postCount = 15;
  excerptLength = 10;
   //-->
    </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="feed_reader.js"></script>
   <!-- END OF FEED READER -->
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script block is not called, I don't think your rss data in feedURL variable is going in correctly.

Comment: It's strange because this script work Local but not in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qQseb/